# Gui busy pop up

Tags: c#

I have a gui. When I press a button my gui interacts with a software. It takes some seconds. During this time I want a dialog box, pop up or some thing like that to appear infront of  my gui which tells the user to wait (with a message). When interaction of gui with software finishes the pop up automatically closes and user can again normally interact with gui.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to spin off a thread so as not to tie up the UI thread.  This is typically achieved via a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

There's a [walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33885/Working-with-BackgroundWorker-Creating-Your-Own-Lo) for setting all this up on codeplex.  The loading form closes when the backgroundworker is complete.

Comment: When ever I press button I start serial comm. The interation of app with software is now happening on another thread (other than main gui thread). Will the solution suggested by you will work in this case

Comment: I'm using serial communication quite often, and always doing it on a background thread, so in most of scenarios the answer is yes I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is briefly how it can be done using the BackgroundWorker component.

Put a BackgroundWorker onto your Form, then in the button's Click handler show your popup indicator Form above the current form, and start your worker with its RunWorkerAsync method. Handle the workers DoWork event, and it the handler, run the long running task. Also handle the worker's completed event (not sure now how it's called exactly), and in that hide your popup form. You can track the operation result in the DoWork event eventargs (Result property), and also you can catch any exceptions during the long running task with the completed event eventarg's Error peroperty. The operation progress can be reported in the DoWork handler with the worker's ReportProgress method, and it can be catched in the GUI with the worker's corresponding event.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set mouse cursor to wait before long running operation

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

and than back to normal, then it's finished

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```